# Changing Radio button Input template using CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like change structure but it does not work, it's always the same structure. How to solve my problem?

```
 <?php
$default = 'wepay';
$options = array('wepay' => 'WePay', 'paypal' => 'Paypal', 'donorbank' => 'Donor Bank');
echo $this->Form->input('payment_method', [
    'templates' => [
        'radioWrapper' => '<label class="radio-inline">{{label}}</label>'],
    'type'      => 'radio',
    'options'   => $options,
    'default'   => $default
]);
?>
```

But this code does not generate output properly. I want to generate output like below:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="wepay" id="payment-method-wepay" checked="checked">WePay
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="paypal" id="payment-method-paypal">Paypal
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="donorbank" id="payment-method-donorbank">Donor Bank
</label>
```

**My Code generate output like below:**

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <label for="payment-method-wepay">
        <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="wepay" id="payment-method-wepay" checked="checked">WePay
    </label>
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <label for="payment-method-paypal">
        <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="paypal" id="payment-method-paypal">Paypal
    </label>
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <label for="payment-method-donorbank"><input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="donorbank" id="payment-method-donorbank">Donor Bank
    </label>
</label>
```

Here one extra label field added. How can I remove this extra-label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are showing there is pretty much the default output, except for the `class` attribute and the missing `for` attribute on the label. So what you want to modify most probably is the `nestingLabel` template, surely not the `radioWrapper` one:

```
 'nestingLabel' =>
     '{{hidden}}<label class="radio-label"{{attrs}}>{{input}}{{text}}</label>'
```

If you want to remove the `for` attribute, then you'll have to remove the `{{attrs}}` placeholder, that way no further attributes can be added to the `label` element.

Comment: i want to remove label for like this  <label for="payment-method-wepay">

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: @Faisal I don't really get what you're asking. You want to remove the `for` attribute?

Comment: yeah with label tag

Comment: @Faisal In that case remove `{{attrs}}` from the template.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solved my problem using @ndm hints. Final solution like this below

```
<?php
$default = 'wepay';
$options = array('wepay' => 'WePay', 'paypal' => 'Paypal', 'donorbank' => 'Donor Bank');
echo $this->Form->input('payment_method', [
    'nestingLabel' =>
         '{{hidden}}<label class="radio-inline"{{attrs}}>{{input}}{{text}}</label>',
    'type'      => 'radio',
    'options'   => $options,
    'default'   => $default
]);
?>
```

Hope this solution help others in future.